# Filling arguments to IList<node>

Tags: c#, list

I am doing merge sort with line-list. How to fill this with arguments, I mean test.

```
{
    IList<Node> testas = new List<Node>();
    Sort(testas);
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately your question is not very clear. What do you mean with "fill this with arguments"? Please expand your question so that it is possible to understand what you're asking

Answer (score -1):

IList is an interface and your custom class should implement this interface. 
This example on MSDN site might be helpful.

[IList example on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Ok Let me try to explain you this.

Lets take an example that you have a class called **Node** which has two properties defined like this

```
public class Node
{
string s1;
string s2;
}
```

now to call them the way you want, I think you should do like this

```
{
    IList<Node> testas = new List<Node>{s1="Abc" ,s2="Xyz"};
    Sort(testas);
}
```